# How can I get a copy of a letter / notice from the IRS from 2004?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs

How can I get a copy of a letter / notice from the IRS from 2004? Or is there a way for me to get a statement from the IRS that I've made a payment on that letter or notice?

Answer (score 2):

Ordered from fastest to slowest, you could try:

- [Registering](https://www.irs.gov/payments/view-your-tax-account) for your account online and looking for your notice
- [Requesting](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript) a transcript for 2003 or 2004, as appropriate
- Calling to make an appointment at a [local IRS office](https://www.irs.gov/help/contact-your-local-irs-office)